# Notification should stops once the condition is met

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, alarmmanager

The app will notify every minute if there are some data in the Array, but once the array is empty, the notification should stop but it does not. The data inside my array are derived from firebase realtime database.

This is my code for that. it is inside **addChildEventListener**.

**listEth** is the array. I can call the data in the database just fine.

```
if (listEth.contains(null)){
     // it will do nothing if there is no data
} else {
   NotifyUsers();      // notify every 24 hours
   notification();     // 
}
```

This is for my **AlarmManager**

```
public final void NotifyUsers(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyPendingAssignments.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                60000, pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 1 min
    }
```

This is how the data is called

```
databaseEth.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){ 
             assignmentEth assignmentEth = dataSnapshot.getValue
                  (com.example.timemanagementapp.assignmentEth.class);
             listEth.add(assignmentEth);
         }
         myAdapterEth.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
     }
});
```

I tried adding another notification channel that will continuously notify when the user opens it, and stops when the array is empty. It works.

```
private void notification() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel("eth", "eth", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "eth")
                    .setContentText("New Assignment")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText("You have new assignment in ETH");

            NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            managerCompat.notify(120, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

But what I need is the notification with the BroadcastReceiver **(NotifyUsers())** so that it will notify even if the app is not open

This is my code for **CreateNotificationChannel()**

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            CharSequence name = "notifyPendingAssignment";
            String description = "You have pending assignments in ETH";

            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notifyPendingAssignment", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

and this is my BroadcastReceiver for **CreateNotificationChannel()**

```
public class NotifyPendingAssignments extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyPendingAssignment")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
                .setContentTitle("Pending Assignment")
                .setContentText("You still have pending assignments.")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(202, builder.build());
    }
}
```

and this is my **NotifyUser()**

```
public final void NotifyUsers(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyPendingAssignments.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                60000, pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 1 min
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, can you share how you call the data?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving the if else condition with *NotifyUser()* and setting the AlarmManager inside that condition.

```
if (listEth.isEmpty() || listEth.contains(null)){
      Toast.makeText(AssignmentListEth.this, "There is no Pending Assignment",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
      pendingIntent.cancel();
} else {
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    60000, pendingIntent);  // every 1 minute
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the answer and post the code as text, not image. Read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) why?